# No such element exception working with a Scanner

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am having a problem while using a Scanner and I do not know how to solve it, kind of new in Java. I have created a menu to read an input char provided by the user through a Scanner and I read options from the menu with this loop:

```
/**
 * Constant to exit the menu.
 */
private static final char EXIT = 'E';

public void run() {
    char option = EXIT;
    do {
        menu.show();
        option = menu.readOption();
        
        try {
            processOption(option);
        } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
            handleSystemError(exception);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            handleUserError(exception);
        }
    } while (option != EXIT);
    
}
```

This is what the method readOption does :

```
public char readOption() {
    return Console.readChar(" Option ");
}
```

And this is what the method readChar does :

```
public static char readChar(String msg) {
    out.println( msg + ": ");
    keyboard.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
    char res = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    keyboard.reset();
    return res;
}
```

The problem is, the loop in its first performance works perfectly fine. The program works propperly. But after the first performance, when it starts again, in the line where it readsOption, it throws a NoSuchElementException and I have been many hours trying to solve it and I do not know how to. Apparently the problem is in the method readChar, when I try to do "keyboard.next()" it throws the no such element exception. Cannot explain that it works the first time and not a second one. When first performance, it waits for me to introduce a char as I expect, but in the second one,while I wish to be expected to introduce a char, when "keyboard.next()", it throws the mentioned exception. Having an issue clearly with my Scanner, I hope someone can identify the issue here. Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to solve it thanks to this page: [Solucione el error NoSuchElementException en Java](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/java-nosuchelementexception/#nosuchelementexception-al-usar-la-clase-de-esc%25C3%25A1ner-en-java)

The issue was that because of the size of this program I had to use 2 scanners at the same time, and when I closed one of them, it caused the other one to stop working, throwing that exception.